Нужно приклеить Mesh к камере, в меше служебная информация меню приложения и т.д
Задача, повесить на весь канвас что то типа прозрачного банера с элементами меша в нужной точке экрана в 2Д формате.
Немного по гуглив нашел вот такую конструкцию,
      camera.add(mesh2); // получаем класс камеры
     
      mesh2.position.set(0.1, 0.1, -0.1); // смещаем по координатам

В принципе разумно но конструкция не работает, как быть?

Я не знаю, может моя задумка и рабочая, но пока суть да дело, создал новую сцену, новую камеру да и вывел все это хозяйство через:
renderer.setViewport(0, 0, width/4, height/4); 
renderer.autoClear = true;
renderer.render(scene, camera);
renderer.autoClear = false;
renderer.setViewport(0, 0, width, height);
renderer.render(scene1, camera2);

